# Encrypted login: transcription from javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python, encoding, decoding, transcription

My python code seems to be wrong both for encoding or decoding

Starting from the following script which is part of a server's API:

```
var k = c + b.salt;
          j.mode = 2,
          j.userId = g.user.userId,
          j.pwh = CryptoJS.SHA1(k),
          j.pwh = j.pwh.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64),
          a({
```

my python script gives:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> import base64
>>> 
>>> salt = "HPUETYr0njRoc9A5QVttWNU/OPY="
>>> c = "V6T5BXH2"
>>> pands = c+salt
>>> pands_enc = hashlib.sha1(pands.encode())
>>> pands_enc= pands_enc.hexdigest()
>>> pwh = base64.b64encode(pands_enc.encode())
>>> print(pwh)
b'ZDQ0ZWMzZGY4MmNmNjkzNjJhYmM5YzEwYmE1YzA5OGY2NTNiMzMzOQ=='
```

I am not quite sure about the value returned for c in the javascript, but I assume it to be what I am using in my python script.
The salt comes from the server's webpage/F12, which returns an entirely different value:

```
"pwh": "1E7D34LPaTYqvJwQulwJj2U7Mzk=",
[tag:tag-name]
```

Not being quite sure of the value for c, I tried to decode the pwh value from the server:

```
>>> base64_message = '1E7D34LPaTYqvJwQulwJj2U7Mzk='
>>> base64_bytes = base64_message.encode('ascii')
>>> message_bytes = base64.b64decode(base64_bytes)
>>> message = message_bytes.decode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 0: ordinal not in        range(128)
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I obtained the correct value with this code:

```
import hashlib
import base64

salt = 'HPUETYr0njRoc9A5QVttWNU/OPY='
c = 'V6T5BXH2'
pands = c+salt
pands_enc = hashlib.sha1(pands.encode()).hexdigest()

# from hex to bytes # 
BYTE_ARRAY = bytearray.fromhex(pands_enc)
BASE64_VAL = base64.b64encode(BYTE_ARRAY)

# to ascii #
pwh_string = BASE64_VAL.decode('ascii')
```